# PHP: Unknown Syntax Possibly a Function Without Parentheses?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I just jumped on to a project that was started buy someone else and I am seeing something in the php code that I am not recognizing.

```
$page_title = ISX_MANAGE_ACCT;
$l_pw_err = ISX_PWD_LEN;
echo ISX_CONFIRM_REFUND;
```

There are a lot of these ISX_(...)'s placed throughout the code. They all start with "ISX_" and are in all caps.

Googling ISX produces no answers. I dont think that they are user defined functions because there isnt a "()"  afterwards and because there are no include files that define any functions that would be applicable to these. They are on the other hand the same color in my text editor as functions.

Can anyone tell me what these could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bunch of define statements:

```
define( 'ISX_MANAGE_ACCT', 'Something');
$var = ISX_MANAGE_ACCT;

// Same thing as: $var = 'Something';
```

Comment: Thanks, they are define constants. The problem was that they weren't being defined on the page or any of the includes on that page. I finally found them in an include under an include under an include under an include. Thanks again to both of you for your responses!

Answer (score 2):

They're named constants.

http://php.net/define